# changing string into integer iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In this code I want to change the string founded to integer and want to use it for further processing. How can I do that?
Here the recordId isEqualToString:@"1", I want to change this string "1" into integer and then want to use it

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if (foundRecordId) {
        NSLog(@"didEndElement: %@", recordId);     
    }

    if ([recordId isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

        NSLog(@"Only 1 account");

        MainScreenController *mainScreen1 = [[MainScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainScreen" bundle:nil ];

        self.mainScreen = mainScreen1;

        [self.view addSubview: mainScreen1.view];        
    }

    else if ([recordId isEqualToString:@"0"]){

        NSLog(@"Accounts more than 1");

        ChooseAccountsController *chooseAccount = [[ChooseAccountsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChooseAccountsController" bundle:nil];
        self.chooseAcc = chooseAccount;
        [self.view addSubview:chooseAccount.view];      
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do that. Just use [NSString's](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) `intValue` message.

Your code will be something like:

```
if ([recordId intValue] == 1]) {
    // do what you need when 1
} else if ([recordId intValue] == 0) {
    // do what you need when 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[recordId intValue];
```

Try this one.